# Kotlin/KAPT Generated Kotlin class is not recognized as class member, but it does inside of methods

Tags: java, kotlin, kapt, annotation-processor, kotlinpoet

I have written an annotation processor that generates a builder class for my classes annotated with `@DataBuilder`

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
annotation class DataBuilder
```

My classes annotated with this annotation are located in the `com.my.package.model` package and the generated builder class is also located in the same package `com.my.package.model` but in the generated directory of course `build/generated/source/kapt/debug/com/my/package/model/MyModelBuilder.kt`, I can use these generated classes fine inside of my model classes(written in Kotlin)

**BUT** I can **NOT** use the generated `MyModelBuilder` Kotlin class inside of a java class as a class member

```
package com.my.package.home;
import com.my.package.model.MyModelBuilder;
public class Home {
    MyModelBuilder builder; // <=== AS recognizes the class, but I'm having an compilation issue
}
```

Android Studio recognizes the class, but I’m having this compilation issue

```
com/my/package/home/Home.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
MyModelBuilder builder;
           ^
  symbol:   class MyModelBuilder
  location: class Home
```

it’s weird because I can use this generated builder class only inside of methods, this code compiles fine:

```
package com.my.package.home;
import com.my.package.model.MyModelBuilder;
public class Home {
    public void hello() {
        MyModelBuilder builder;
    }
}
```

could somebody here help me to understand this behavior and how to fix this? In advance, thanks!

**UPDATE**

I just created this repo with the necessary code to replicate the issue
https://github.com/epool/HelloKapt

The project works fine after cloning and running, to replicate the issue please un-comment this line https://github.com/epool/HelloKapt/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/nearsoft/hellokapt/app/MainActivity.java#L13

Note: If I convert my MainActivity.java class to Kotlin(MainActivity.kt) the issues is NOT reproducible and works fine, but I don’t want to do so due to some project limitations so far

**Kotlin Issue:** https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/KT-24591

Comment: Where is the source generated, is the directory added to the source set?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce the source generated is in `...build/generated/source/kapt/debug/...` it's the same directory used by dagger and other annotation processors, my Android Studio recognizes the generated class and I can use the class inside of a method, but not as a class member.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your Github project, I notice that you don't declare a dependency on `kotlin-stdlib-jdk7` in the `app` module. When I build the module, compiler emits the following warnings:

```
warning: unknown enum constant AnnotationTarget.CLASS
  reason: class file for kotlin.annotation.AnnotationTarget not found   
warning: unknown enum constant AnnotationRetention.SOURCE
  reason: class file for kotlin.annotation.AnnotationRetention not found    
warning: unknown enum constant AnnotationTarget.CLASS
  reason: class file for kotlin.annotation.AnnotationTarget not found
```

Since `kotlin-stdlib-jdk7` is declared as `implementation` in the `annotations` module, the `app` module doesn't see it as a transitive dependency, that might be the reason why compilation fails. To fix it, you should probably declare the correct dependency in the `app` module, or at least use `apiElements` scope for `kotlin-stdlib-jdk7` in `annotations`.

The fact that the IDE doesn't notify you that compilation failed might be a tools bug, but there's definitely no underlying Kotlin compiler issue.

Comment: Actually, I created the project with Kotlin support from Android Studio, maybe AS is not adding it by default and it can be resolved in the new kotlin gradle plugins, but not sure. I just pushed the change for adding the kotlin runtime dependency, which didn't help. Anyways good catch.